# Have enum value be equivalent to many others

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I need to use an enum of various values, in this case various building pieces. Most of these are unique, but there a few that I'd like to be equivalent. I mean as follows:

```
enum class EPiece: uint8 {
    Ceiling,
    Table,
    Door,
    WestWall,
    NorthWall,
    SouthWall,
    EastWall,
    Wall,
    Floor
};
```

And I'd like to `Wall == WestWall` to be `true`, as well as `Wall == NorthWall`, etc. However, `WestWall == NorthWall` is false.

Why I am doing this is because I am making a game where various pieces have a definition based off of what they are/where they are. The player has to place various pieces in a predefined order. The player first has to place a `NorthWall` piece. They will have available various pieces, and will have to select a `Wall` piece, and have to attempt to place it on a `NorthWall` piece. The game checks if the two are equivalent (in this case `true`), and if the current piece to place is `NorthWall`. If they attempt to place it on a `WestWall` piece it should fail since it's not that stage yet.

I thought of doing this through flags, doing something like

```
WestWall = 0x01,
NorthWall = 0x02,
SouthWall = 0x04,
EastWall = 0x08,
Wall = WestWall | NorthWall | SouthWall | EastWall
```

and checking by doing something like:

```
// SelectedPiece is the Piece the Player selected and is attempting to place
// PlacedOnPiece is the Piece that we are attempting to place on top of
// CurrentPieceToPlace is what Piece we are supposed to place at this stage
if ((CurrentPieceToPlace == PlacedOnPiece) && (SelectedPiece & PlacedOnPiece != 0)) {
}
```

The thing is, I have a lot of pieces and my understanding is to make the flags work I have to use powers of two. That means if I use `uint32` I could have a max of 32 Pieces, and I don't want to be limited by that. I might only need around 20, but I don't want to get stuck.

Any suggestions? At this point I need to use an enum, so I can't try a different type.

Comment: note that there is also a semantical difference between the concept of flags (what you're trying to do with `Wall`) and enumeration types (destinct, listable types or states). maybe you could be more specific to what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise against overloading `==` to have that meaning.  `==` is usually transitive (if A==B and B==C, then A==C), and if it fails to be transitive otherwise "sane" code will break.

Start with your enum:

```
enum class EPiece: uint8 {
  Ceiling,
  Table,
  Door,
  WestWall,
  NorthWall,
  SouthWall,
  EastWall,
  Wall,
  Floor
};
```

Now define an `can_be_used_as_a` relationship.

```
bool can_be_used_as_a( EPiece x, EPiece used_as_a_y ) {
  if (x==y) return true;
  switch(x) {
    case Wall: {
      switch(used_as_a_y) {
        case WestWall:
        case EastWall:
        case NorthWall:
        case EastWall:
          return true;
        default: break;
      }
    }
    default: break;
  }
  switch(used_as_a_y) {
    case Wall: {
      switch(x) {
        case WestWall:
        case EastWall:
        case NorthWall:
        case EastWall:
          return true;
        default: break;
      }
    }
    default: break;
  }
  return false;
}
```

now `can_be_used_as_a( WestWall, Wall )` is `true` because a `WestWall` can be used as a `Wall`.  And similarly, `Wall` can be used as a `WestWall`.  But a `WestWall` cannot be used as a `EastWall`.

If you want slightly cleaner syntax, we can write a named operator:

```
namespace named_operator {
  template<class D>struct make_operator{make_operator(){}};

  template<class T, char, class O> struct half_apply { T&& lhs; };

  template<class Lhs, class Op>
  half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op> operator*( Lhs&& lhs, make_operator<Op> ) {
    return {std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)};
  }

  template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
  auto operator*( half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op>&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs )
  -> decltype( invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) ) )
  {
    return invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
  }
}
```

for the 12 line named operator library, used like:

```
struct used_as_a_tag{};
static const named_operator::make_operator<used_as_a_tag> can_use_as_a;
bool invoke( EPiece x, used_as_a_tag, EPiece y ) {
  return can_be_used_as_a(x,y);
}
```

and now we can do this:

```
if (x *can_use_as_a* y) {
}
```

with the operator occurring between the left and right operands.  But this might be going too far.

Finally, consider using `enum class` instead of `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

You're going in the right direction. Each wall type you have represents a single bit, and that's awesome. Now all you have to do is to combine them in `Wall`, and to extract them in your checks, so:

```
WestWall = 0x01,  //0b0001
NorthWall = 0x02, //0b0010
SouthWall = 0x04, //0b0100
EastWall = 0x08,  //0b1000
Wall =    0xF  //0b1111
```

Now, to check if one value of the enum represents an other value, you should write something like this:

```
bool isSame(EPiece first, EPiece second)
{
    //if they are the same, they are, well... the same.
    if(first == second)
        return true;
    //this only leaves the bits that are present in both values, so 
    //if the result is different from 0, then second is a part of first, so
    //we return true
    else if(first & second)
        return true;
    //if we are here, then first and second are unrelated
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's basically what I already suggested, but the problem is that to keep all the pieces unique I then need to make them all powers of 2, and I'll run out of bits after 32 (if I use uint32)

Comment: @robev, Well, the only other way would be to make your own compare function with huge `if`s like in John Zwinck's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own comparison operators, like this:

```
bool operator==(EPiece lhs, EPiece rhs)
{
    if (int(lhs) == int(EPiece::Wall) &&
         (int(rhs) == int(EPiece::NorthWall) ||
          int(rhs) == int(EPiece::SouthWall))) // lots more cases...
    {
        return true;
    }

    return int(lhs) == int(rhs);
}
```

Do note that the declaration (though not necessarily the definition) of the above *must* be visible wherever you expect to compare these things, so you should declare it right alongside the enum declaration.

Comment: this might be a source of many programming bugs: this produces different behaviour for `if` and `switch` statements

Answer (score 0):

Here are two slightly different possibilites:

```
enum {
    Flag0 = 1 << 0,
    Flag1 = 1 << 1,
    Flag2 = 1 << 2,
    Flag3 = 1 << 3,

    FlagMask = 0x07
}

if (value & FlagMask) // it's got some flags
    { ... }
if (value & Flag3) // Flag3
    { ... }
```

and

```
enum {
    ItemA0,
    ItemABegin = ItemA0,
    ItemA1,
    ItemA2,
    // insert ItemAs here
    ItemAEnd,

    ItemB0,
    ItemBBegin = ItemB0,
    ItemB1,
    // insert ItemBs here
    ItemBEnd,
}

if (ItemABegin <= value && value < ItemAEnd) // it's some ItemA
    { ... }
if (ItemBBegin <= value && value < ItemBEnd) // it's some ItemB
    { ... }

switch (value) { // switch on specific types
    case ItemB0: ... break;
    case ItemB1: ... break;
}
```

the second version still encapsulates the idea of an enumeration type.